# GTK3 MenuItem checkbutton + icon?

Tags: gtk3, menuitem, menubar, pygobject

A piece of GTK software in my company features a menubar with some menu items in the menu bar being check buttons, and/or having an icon beside their label. However the menu is created using `Gtk.UIManager` and `Gtk.ActionGroup`, which are now both deprecated and are causing issues. For this reason, we are trying to rewrite the menu bar without these classes.

I've looked at the [documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/MenuItem.html#methods) for the `Gtk.MenuItem` class, and it only seems possible to set the item's text. No way to place an icon inline, or make the menu item togglable like a check button.

Is there another way to achieve this, say place a little HBox inside the MenuItem, or is this no longer possible with non-deprecated features of GTK3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might reference the following link that describes a GTK image menu item.

"https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ImageMenuItem.html"

If you want to stay with using a plain GTK menu item, you might reference the equivalent functionality discussion under the "Class Details" section.  Basically, what one would do is as follows:

- define and create a GTK box widget.
- define and create a label widget.
- define and create an image/icon widget.
- define and create a menu item widget.
- add the icon widget and label widget to the box widget.
- add the box widget to the menu item widget.

I am more familiar with "C" than Python so here is my code snippet that I added to a sample program to add the "exit" image to my "Quit" menu item.

```
GtkWidget *box;
GtkWidget *icon;
GtkWidget *label;
GtkWidget *quitMi;

quitMi      = gtk_menu_item_new();
icon        = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name ("application-exit", GTK_ICON_SIZE_MENU);
box         = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 6);
label       = gtk_label_new ("Quit");

gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), icon);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), label);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (quitMi), box);
```

It should be straightforward to interpret what the equivalent Python code would be.

The result of this is an icon with the "Quit" menu item.

[image: Menu item with image]

For menu items with a check mark, I would think that you could use a "GtkCheckMenuItem" widget.  Again, here is a "C" program code snippet illustrating the creation of a check menu item (one should be able to determine the equivalent Python code).

```
GtkWidget *tog_stat;

tog_stat = gtk_check_menu_item_new_with_label("View statusbar");
gtk_check_menu_item_set_active(GTK_CHECK_MENU_ITEM(tog_stat), TRUE);
```

And here is a sample illustration of that type of menu item.

[image: Sample check menu item]

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are only into the gtk3 in linux world, you can use [libxfce4ui](https://developer.xfce.org/libxfce4ui/libxfce4ui-Gtk-Extensions.html) gtk extension widgets. See [xfce_gtk_image_menu_item_new](https://developer.xfce.org/libxfce4ui/libxfce4ui-Gtk-Extensions.html#xfce-gtk-image-menu-item-new).
Example code creating a menubar and using icon from embeded gresource file.

```
// window: this is your gtk_application_window_new
GtkWidget* load_menubar (GtkWidget *window)
{
    GtkWidget *menuBar;
    GtkWidget *menuItem1;
    GtkWidget *menu1;
    GtkWidget *menuQuit;
    GtkWidget *imageQuit;
    
    // extract icon from your resource path
    // you can also use any gtk_image_new_* methods
    imageQuit = gtk_image_new_from_resource ("/menu/icons/quit");
    
    menuBar = gtk_menu_bar_new ();
    menuItem1 = gtk_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic ("_Archivo");
    menu1 = gtk_menu_new ();
    menuQuit = xfce_gtk_image_menu_item_new ("_Salir", NULL, NULL, G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), G_OBJECT(window), imageQuit, GTK_MENU_SHELL (menu1));
        
    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu (GTK_MENU_ITEM (menuItem1), menu1);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (menuBar), menuItem1);
    
    return menuBar;
}
```